# Yii какие права нужно указывать для папок Assets и Runtime?

Tags: php, yii, apache, permissions

На сервере работает фреймворк Yii. Какие права необходимо задавать папкам assets и runtime? Я задал обоим папкам права 777, это позволяет Yii создавать и удалять файлы в этих папках. Но я уверен, что так делать не правильно. Помогите разобраться с этим вопросом.

Answer (score 1):

если не нужно редактирование папок и файлов в них, то лучше всего давать 
`chmod -R u=rw,go=r assets`

Answer (score -1):

Поему вы так не уверенны? Все норм с правами, для них 777 самый раз.

Comment: потому что 777 это free for all, что с точки зрения администрирования является грубой ошибкой

Comment: По правилам нужно конечно поставить на папки права и пользователя апача, но в чем это такое уж нарушение? Если тебя ломанули тут уже нифига не поможет и явно не права на эти папки.

Comment: Чтоб тебя не ломанули, у тебя должны стоять права на папки.

Comment: Что бы что либо сделать с этими папками, тебе все равно потребуется доступ к системе, а права тут ни чего не решают. Так что не надо говорить что меня ламанут из за пары папок с 777...

Comment: Я бы сказал так: лучше назначить норм права на папки, но чего страшного не произойдет если assets и runtime будут 777.

Comment: Веб-сервер - это уже само по себе доступ к системе.

Comment: К слову сказать при развертывании basic/advanced app их скрипт ставит на указанные диры 777.